# Azimuth calculation, extending lines

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, azimuth

I am trying to create a line feature as the result of another line in PyQGIS. The new line should start, where the old "ends", face the "same direction" and should have a defined length of X.

Unfortunately, the direction of both lines is not the same using the following code. What is wrong?:

```
p1 = QgsPointXY(14.18064, 50.63963)
p2 = QgsPointXY(14.15027, 50.66042)

d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
degrees = p1.azimuth(p2)
rad = math.radians(degrees)
# distance is 1000m
d_upfront = d.computeSpheroidProject(p2,1000,rad)
line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=4326", "Measurements AUTO", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(line_layer)
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p1, p2])
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(line)
line2 = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p2, d_upfront])
feat2 = QgsFeature()
feat2.setGeometry(line2)
provider = line_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addFeatures([feat,feat2])

provider.forceReload()
line_layer.reload()
line_layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The example shows the difference: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of the azimuth is not the right way to do it. You will get ideal results if you switch to a bearing calculation:

```
p1 = QgsPointXY(14.18064, 50.63963)
p2 = QgsPointXY(14.15027, 50.66042)
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
# distance is 1000m
d_upfront = d.computeSpheroidProject(p2,1000,d.bearing(p1,p2))
line_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Linestring?crs=EPSG:4326", "Measurements AUTO", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(line_layer)
line = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p1, p2])
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(line)
line2 = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([p2, d_upfront])
feat2 = QgsFeature()
feat2.setGeometry(line2)
provider = line_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addFeatures([feat,feat2])

provider.forceReload()
line_layer.reload()
line_layer.triggerRepaint()
```