# Azimuth calculation in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, azimuth, bearing

I am calculating the azimuth between two points whose position is defined in WGS84 coordinates. If I Open Attribute Table -> Open Field Calculator and ask for

```
degrees(
    azimuth(
        make_point(6.020323,47.248690),
        make_point(6.083703,47.242157)
        )
    )
```

I get 95.885° degrees which is inconsistent with the manual calculation

```
atan2(sin(delta_lon)*cos(lat2), cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(delta_lon))
```

or with the result provided by the French Geographic Institute (Géoportail) web site.

However, if following [Azimuth calculation, extending lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357403/azimuth-calculation-extending-lines) I run in the Python Console:

```py
p1 = QgsPointXY(6.020323,47.248690)
p2 = QgsPointXY(6.083703,47.242157)
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
d.bearing(p1,p2)*180/3.1415926535
```

then I get the correct result of 98.584. Could someone enlighten me as to why the first method provides an erroneous result?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

The [`azimuth()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#azimuth) function calculates the **Cartesian** angle **y-axis-based** clockwise in the Cartesian plane of the coordinate reference system in which are expressed the coordinates of the given points.

To obtain a closer result (True-North-based clockwise, loxodromic) using a Cartesian angle calculation, you shouldn't use a geographical coordinate reference system, but e.g. a conformal projected one, as a proper UTM projection, and then correct the result taking into account the grid convergence at the first point (see [Calculating convergence angle for point data in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339161/calculating-convergence-angle-for-point-data-in-qgis)).

The `QgsDistanceArea.bearing()` function, instead, calculates the **geodesic** bearing angle **True-North-based** clockwise **on the specified ellipsoid** (orthodromic) from the given WGS 84 geographical coordinates, or from the coordinates expressed in another coordinate reference system just setting it with the `QgsDistanceArea` function [`setSourceCrs()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDistanceArea.html#a836191959392b8bbe2fa82ec2aa28ce3)